# Joint moment generating function of (X,Y)

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm looking for the E[XY] of the joint moment generating function of a couple of random variables (X,Y). We don't know if the variables are independent. I don't know how to solve the partial derivative ∂² E[e^(sX+tY)] ∂s ∂t

Comment: What information *do* you have about the variables?

Comment: I don't have any information, I think I need to find a general equation for the (X,Y) couple

Comment: Do we at least know if continuous of discrete they are?

Comment: I suppose they are continuous